# Custom JSON to populate a Datatable

Tags: java, jquery, json, datatable

Im creating a DataTable from an Ajax json.

```
resultTable = $('#changeTable').DataTable({
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "pageLength": 50,
            "scrollX": true,
            "lengthMenu":[[50,100,250, -1], [50, 100, 250, "All"]],
            "dom":'<"toolbar">ltipr', //write ltfipr to show a search bar
            "ajax":{
                url:"api/changes",
                "dataType":"json",
                timeout:15000
            }
    });
```

The DataTables creates but it shows an error:

> DataTables warning: table id=changeTable - Requested unknown parameter
>   '0' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please
>   see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My JSON Looks like the following

```
{"data":
    [
       {"id":1,
        "createdDate":"Apr 18, 2018 4:10:58 PM",
        "source":"manual upload",
        "emailId":"manual upload",
        "attachmentId":"manual upload",
        ...,},
       {next objet}]}
```

Such JSON object is created in my Java controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/changes", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getChanges(){
        Optional<List<PriceChange>> priceChangeList = pcService.findAllPriceChanges();
        JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
        if (priceChangeList.isPresent()) {
            result.add("data", new Gson().toJsonTree(priceChangeList.get()));
            return  result.toString();
        }
        return null;

    }
```

I don know how to use this information with the `dataSrc` property to make it work for the DataTable. Any Ideas?

Comment: What is `pcService`? What does it return? Please provide more context about `dataSrc`.

Comment: Have you tried deserialization using Jackson instead of GSON?

Comment: You have `result = new JsonObject();` but looks like your `"{ data": []` is a JsonArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define [**`columns`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns) for the table.  If you have

```
<table id="changeTable"></table>
```

add this to your DataTables options :

```
resultTable = $('#changeTable').DataTable({
  ...,
  columns: [
     { data: 'id', title: 'id' },
     { data: 'createdDate', title: 'createdDate' },
     { data: 'source', title: 'source' },
     { data: 'emailId', title: 'emailId' },
     { data: 'attachmentId', title: 'attachmentId' }
   ]
})
```

If ypu have specifed a `<thead>` section you can skip the `title`'s.